# Generic makefile with files in different directories

Tags: makefile

I want develop a generic makefile for the folowing architecture:

```
30/04/2015  18:10    <REP>          .
30/04/2015  18:10    <REP>          ..
30/04/2015  18:08    <REP>          exe
30/04/2015  17:22    <REP>          headers
30/04/2015  17:53               726 makefile.txt
30/04/2015  18:08    <REP>          objects
30/04/2015  17:53    <REP>          sources
```

with:

The content of sources

```
 30/04/2015  17:53    <REP>          .
 30/04/2015  17:53    <REP>          ..
 30/04/2015  17:22               124 main.c
```

and the content of headers:

```
  30/04/2015  17:22    <REP>          .
  30/04/2015  17:22    <REP>          ..
  30/04/2015  17:22                20 myheader.h
```

Objects : contents the output object files.

exe: contents the executable

When I put the header files and sources in the same directory, the makefile generates the output. But when I separate them, the make generates an error during dependency.

Here is my current makefile:

```
SRCDIRS   = ../Mydirectory/sources
HDRDIRS   = ../Mydirectory/headers     
SRCEXTS = .c  
HDREXTS = .h 
OUTPUT = Output 
CC= gcc
SOURCES = $(foreach file,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(file)/*,.c)))
HEADERS = $(foreach file,$(HDRDIRS),$(wildcard $(addprefix $(file)/*,.h)))

OBJS    = $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SOURCES)))
DEPS    = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

DEP_OPT     = -M
DEPEND      = $(CC)  $(DEP_OPT)
DEPEND.d    = $(subst -g ,,$(DEPEND))
COMPILE.c   = $(CC)  -c -I $(HDRDIRS)
LINK.c      = $(CC)


all: $(OUTPUT)

%.d:%.c
[TAB]@echo -n $(dir $<) > $@
@$(DEPEND.d) $< >> $@ 

objs:$(OBJS)

%.o:%.c
[TAB]$(COMPILE.c) $< -o $@  

$(OUTPUT):$(OBJS)
[TAB]$(LINK.c)   $(OBJS) -o $@ 

clean:
[TAB]$(RM) $(OBJS) $(OUTPUT).exe
```

Update:
The makefile is in Mydirectory.

The output of make -f makefile.txt :

in MS-DOS:

```
 gcc -c -I ../Mydirectory/headers ../Mydirectory/sources/main.c -o   ../Mydirectory/sources/main.o
 gcc ../Mydirectory/sources/main.o -o Output
```

And two files are created:

```
objects/main.o
Mydirectory/Output.exe
```

Comment: Where is that makefile in the hierarchy? Where are your object files supposed to go? You don't seem to be using the `.d` files anywhere.  Your default target is `$(OUTPUT)` but that doesn't use the `exe` directory or end in `.exe`. What error are you getting when you run `make`?

Comment: For moment i put all the output files (*.o and *.exe) in Mydirectory.

Comment: I assume your error is about not finding the source files for the object file targets? That's because your `%.o:%.c` pattern target doesn't include the source path in the prerequisite section.

Comment: the output of make is:  ../Mydirectory/sources/main.c:1:22 myheader.h: No such file or directory
make: ***[../Mydirectory/sources/main.o] Error 1

Comment: So i must be %.o:%.c %.h instead of %.o:%.c?

Comment: That error is from your compiler and means you didn't give it the correct `-I` flag to the header directory. But that you go there at all is surprising because with that makefile I don't see how you should have been able to. Can you include an actual `ls`-style output of your hierarchy and make sure that that is **exactly** the makefile you are using.

Comment: I modified the code : COMPILE.c   = $(CC)  -c -I $(HDRDIRS) and it works.
Now how can I put obj files and exe files in objects and exe directories?

Comment: You don't need to modify `COMPILE.c` for that just put your `-I` flag in `CPPFLAGS` (used by the default `COMPILE.c`). Like I said, update your post with `ls`-style output of your directory structure and files and make sure that's the **exact** makefile you are using. As written I don't believe that makefile above should be compiling your object files at all.

Comment: When you run make are you running `make -f makefile.txt`? Can you also post the output of running whatever make command you run with a clean directory?

Comment: Ah, I was mis-remembering what `$(basename)` did. You need to fix the path to the files in `$(OBJS)` to be `objects/` and not `sources/` and then you probably need `objects/%.o: sources/%.c:` as your target.